# gwt-maven-plugin how to add the source jar in another module pom.xml

Tags: gwt, maven

my application has 2 module, one is jar and the other is gwt war. in the jar module (non-gwt) pom.xml, I add

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      <executions>
         <execution>
           <phase>package</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

and als-admin-viewer-core-1.0.0-sources.jar is successfully created.
Then In the webapp(a gwt application) pom.xml, I want to use this jar, and in the  segment, I add

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo<groupId>
   <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>hk.gov.ehr.service.tch.als</groupId>
    <artifactId>als-admin-viewer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>    
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>hk.gov.ehr.service.tch.als</groupId>
    <artifactId>als-admin-viewer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <execution>
  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
  <goals> 
    <goal>compile</goal>
  </goals>
  </executions>
........
```

but when I run maven install for this project (als-admin-viewer-webapp), error 
No source code is available for type hk.gov.ehr.service.tch.als.admin.viewer.core.LogSearchCriteria; did you forget to inherit a required module?
is prompted.

what is the problem?!!

I even try to add

```
<compileSourcesArtifacts>
  <compileSourcesArtifact>hk.gov.ehr.service.tch.als:als-admin-viewer-core</compileSourcesArtifact>  <!-- groupId:artifactId -->
</compileSourcesArtifacts>
```

in

```
<configuration>
```

section of gwt-maven-plugin, but it still does not help!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to create "gwt.xml" file in your jar module and inherit it in your main gwt.xml (inside gwt maven module).

Please look at
 http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/library.html

for details (section "Using general purpose JARs as GWT library").

Also bear in mind: if you're using maven-source-plugin to attach sources, your sources will be distributed with the web application. And if you're using "compileSourcesArtifacts" you avoid this side-effect.